# validation function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation

I have created a java script function, it should validate the input character that should contain 10 characters and can contain  alphanumeric characters, but this function does not work, please help me

```js
function ValidateNIC(id)
{
 
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;
 
 while(id.value.length==10)
    if(id.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('NIC must have alphanumeric characters only or should contain 10 charaters');
        id.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it cannot be blank as well

Comment: Why the `while` loop?

Comment: what does not work? what is your issue? Set up a fiddle pls

Comment: Using a `while` there instead of an `if` is really bad form, BTW.

Comment: Use `console.log(id.value)` to insure it is the value you expect (not enough info in your question to be sure).

Comment: I have a form that i can enter national ID number init and once i click on submit button it should validate the length (length should = 10) and it cannot be null, how do i write a function for it? above function dosent work

Comment: If you want the length to be exactly 10, you can use `{10}` in the regexp instead of `+`. Then you don't need to test the length separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code as it stands, if the length is not 10, then nothing else happens.  A better approach might be:

```
if ((id.value.length == 10) && id.value.match(letters)) {
    return true;
}
alert("NIC must ...");
id.focus();
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the conditions for validation in Regex like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$`. Note that additional `{10}` in the regex pattern string for creating a match only when the length is **10 exactly**.

Then you can make use of the `Regex` Object `test` method, which test the regex pattern against a string and returns `true` if the match is successful and false otherwise.

Complete modified snippet below with positive and negative test cases.

```js
function ValidateNIC(id){
    
    var aphaPattern10 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$/g;
    var result = aphaPattern10.test(id.value);

 if(!result){
      alert('NIC must have alphanumeric characters only or should contain 10 charaters');
        //id.focus();
      }
      return result;
 
}

var testObjPass = { value : "012345678a"}
console.log(ValidateNIC(testObjPass));

var testObjFail = { value : "012345678a21312"}
console.log(ValidateNIC(testObjFail));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks the following 
NIC must have alphanumeric characters only or should contain 10 charaters.
So if it is only 10 characters then it will not alert else, it will test the regex. Considering id is an object with key value

```
  function ValidateNIC(id)
  {
      var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    if(id.value.length!==10){
      if(id.value.match(letters))
      {
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          alert('NIC must have alphanumeric characters only or should contain 10 charaters');
          id.focus();
          return false;
      }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Replacing the `while` with an `if` is good, but your code still has the faults of the original.

Comment: I did not change the logic, It just does what the alert condition wants it to do. It checks that the NIC code should be either 10 characters long or should be alphanumeric